# SqlAlchemy recreates pool after engine.dispose()

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy with `pandas.to_sql()` to copy some data into SQL server. After the copying is done and `engine.dispose()` is called, I see the following INFO message in logs:

```
[INFO] sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool: Pool recreating
```

I was wondering if this message means that even though I dispose of the engine, the connection is still being kept live. And if so, what would be the safe and correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The connection is not alive. But you can restart the connection with the help of the `Pool` object.

This is described in detail in the [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/pooling.html#disconnect-handling-optimistic):

> The Engine has logic which can detect disconnection events and refresh the pool automatically.
>
> When the Connection attempts to use a DBAPI connection, and an exception is raised that corresponds to a “disconnect” event, the connection is invalidated. The Connection then calls the Pool.recreate() method, effectively invalidating all connections not currently checked out so that they are replaced with new ones upon next checkout.

Also check out the code example in the link. It is really neat.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a connection which is already checked out from the pool, those connections will still be alive as they are being referenced by something.

You may refer to following links for detailed information. 
https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py#L2512-L2539
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#engine-disposal
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Engine.dispose

If you are using QueuePool (its by default if you don't specify any poolClass when creating engine object) and doesn't want any connections to be kept alive then you may close the connection [conn.close() or session.close()] which in-turn returns the connection back to the pool (called checked-in connection). Later when you call engine.dispose() after you copy job is done, that will take care of closing the connection really and won't be keep any checked-in connections alive